# How do I successfully use put and delete for React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, put, http-delete

I'm having trouble with an assignment that requires us to make axios put and delete calls in React.  I successfully managed to render the data using .get, but anything else related to the data, such as editing and deleting, I get an error related to the empty array I'm pushing data to.  I have to use a unique, dynamic id.  For that I'm using useParams and useHistory(had to delete this method because it was acting up).

The problem from there is aligning the data with the proper syntax for both the .put and .delete calls.

colorList.js

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axiosWithAuth from '../utils/axiosWithAut';
import {useParams} from 'react-router-dom';

const initialColor = {
  color: "",
  code: { hex: "" }
};

const ColorList = ({ colors, updateColors }) => {
  console.log(colors);
  const [editing, setEditing] = useState(false);
  const [colorToEdit, setColorToEdit] = useState(initialColor);

  const { id } = useParams();
 
  const editColor = color => {
    setEditing(true);
    setColorToEdit(color);
  };

  const saveEdit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Make a put request to save your updated color
    // think about where will you get the id from...
    // where is is saved right now?

    axiosWithAuth().put(`/api/colors/${id}`, colorToEdit)
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res.data)
      updateColors = colors.map(colr => {
        if(colr.id === colorToEdit.id) {
          return colorToEdit;
        }
        return colr;
      })
      setColorToEdit(updateColors);
    })
    .catch(err => console.error("ERROR", err.message))
  };

  
  
  
  const deleteColor = color => {
    // make a delete request to delete this color

    axiosWithAuth().delete(`/api/colors/${id}`)
    .then(res => {
      setColorToEdit(res.data);
    })
    .catch(err => console.error("ERROR", err.message))
  };

  return (
    <div className="colors-wrap">
      <p>colors</p>
      <ul>
        {colors.map(color => (
          <li key={color.color} onClick={() => editColor(color)}>
            <span>
              <span className="delete" onClick={e => {
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    deleteColor(color)
                  }
                }>
                  x
              </span>{" "}
              {color.color}
            </span>
            <div
              className="color-box"
              style={{ backgroundColor: color.code.hex }}
            />
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
      {editing && (
        <form onSubmit={saveEdit}>
          <legend>edit color</legend>
          <label>
            color name:
            <input
              onChange={e =>
                setColorToEdit({ ...colorToEdit, color: e.target.value })
              }
              value={colorToEdit.color}
            />
          </label>
          <label>
            hex code:
            <input
              onChange={e =>
                setColorToEdit({
                  ...colorToEdit,
                  code: { hex: e.target.value }
                })
              }
              value={colorToEdit.code.hex}
            />
          </label>
          <div className="button-row">
            <button type="submit">save</button>
            <button onClick={() => setEditing(false)}>cancel</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      )}
      <div className="spacer" />
      {/* stretch - build another form here to add a color */}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ColorList;
```

server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const CORS = require("cors");

const app = express();
const token =
  "ahuBHejkJJiMDhmODZhZi0zaeLTQ4ZfeaseOGZgesai1jZWYgrTA07i73Gebhu98";

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(CORS());

let colors = [
  {
    color: "aliceblue",
    code: {
      hex: "#f0f8ff"
    },
    id: 1
  },
  {
    color: "limegreen",
    code: {
      hex: "#99ddbc"
    },
    id: 2
  },
  {
    color: "aqua",
    code: {
      hex: "#00ffff"
    },
    id: 3
  },
  {
    color: "aquamarine",
    code: {
      hex: "#7fffd4"
    },
    id: 4
  },
  {
    color: "lilac",
    code: {
      hex: "#9a99dd"
    },
    id: 5
  },
  {
    color: "softpink",
    code: {
      hex: "#dd99ba"
    },
    id: 6
  },
  {
    color: "bisque",
    code: {
      hex: "#dd9a99"
    },
    id: 7
  },
  {
    color: "softyellow",
    code: {
      hex: "#dcdd99"
    },
    id: 8
  },
  {
    color: "blanchedalmond",
    code: {
      hex: "#ffebcd"
    },
    id: 9
  },
  {
    color: "blue",
    code: {
      hex: "#6093ca"
    },
    id: 10
  },
  {
    color: "blueviolet",
    code: {
      hex: "#8a2be2"
    },
    id: 11
  }
];

let nextId = 12;

function authenticator(req, res, next) {
  const { authorization } = req.headers;
  if (authorization === token) {
    next();
  } else {
    res.status(403).json({ error: "User must be logged in to do that." });
  }
}

app.post("/api/login", (req, res) => {
  const { username, password } = req.body;
  if (username === "Lambda School" && password === "i<3Lambd4") {
    req.loggedIn = true;
    setTimeout(() => {
      res.status(200).json({
        payload: token
      });
    }, 1000);
  } else {
    res
      .status(403)
      .json({ error: "Username or Password incorrect. Please see Readme" });
  }
});

app.get("/api/colors", authenticator, (req, res) => {
  res.send(colors);
});

app.post("/api/colors", authenticator, (req, res) => {
  if (req.body.color !== undefined && req.body.code !== undefined) {
    const newcolor = req.body;
    newcolor.id = nextId;
    colors.push(newcolor);
  }
  nextId = nextId + 1;
  res.status(201).json(colors);
});

app.put("/api/colors/:id", authenticator, (req, res) => {
  if (!req.params.id)
    res.status(400).send("Your request is missing the color id");
  if (req.body.id === undefined || !req.body.color || !req.body.code) {
    res
      .status(422)
      .send("Make sure your request body has all the fields it needs");
  }
  colors = colors.map(color => {
    if (`${color.id}` === req.params.id) {
      return req.body;
    }
    return color;
  });
  res.status(200).send(req.body);
});

app.delete("/api/colors/:id", authenticator, (req, res) => {
  if (!req.params.id)
    res.status(400).send("Your request is missing the color id");
  colors = colors.filter(color => `${color.id}` !== req.params.id);
  res.status(202).send(req.params.id);
});

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.send("App is working ");
});

app.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log("Server listening on port 5000");
});
```

There are also a few other components, but I'm not sure if they're relevent to the problem I'm having.

Comment: what exactly is the error you're getting?

Comment: ```
×
TypeError: Cannot read property 'hex' of undefined
ColorList
C:/Users/Brian/Documents/GitHub/react-bubbles/client/src/components/ColorList.js:110
  107 |         code: { hex: e.target.value }
  108 |       })
  109 |     }
> 110 |     value={colorToEdit.code.hex}
      | ^  111 |   />
  112 | </label>
  113 | <div className="button-row">
```

Comment: That seems to be a problem with React rather than Axios or your backend. At some point in your code, the `color`'s shape get unintentionally changed, thus making `color.code` undefined. To be honest, your code looks pretty good to me, I really cannot tell the exact error. I suggest you do some "print debugging" with `console.log` to see where it goes wrong - either the data you received from backend is malformatted - or authentication goes wrong and you get weird error message that you thought were colors - or you did some accidental transformation when passing data/props, etc.